# What does `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance` mean, and how to fix?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

This was previously working fine, but now I'm getting the error `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`. What does it mean by `spread non-iterable instance`?

I'm making a call to get a list of user ids, and then running through each id to get add convos, and then adding to redux. This previously worked fine, and now is throwing the above error.

```
      this.props.matchUserIds.matchUserIds.matchUserIds.map(id => {
          apiHelper.getProfileInfo(token, id).then(results => {
            const match = results.data.data
            match.isBlocked = false

            apiHelper.getConvoByUsers(this.props.currentUser.authToken, match.user.id)
              .then(results => {
                  if(results.data.data.length > 0) {
                    match.convoExists = true
                    match.convoId = results.data.data[0].id
                  } else {
                    match.convoExists = false
                  }

                  this.props.addMatchesProfile({matchUserProfiles: match})
  ...
```

MatchesActions.js

```
import {
  GET_MATCHES,
  ADD_MATCHES_PROFILES,
  RESET_MATCHES,
} from './types'

export const addMatchesProfile = ({ matchUserProfiles }) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_MATCHES_PROFILES,
    payload: { matchUserProfiles }
  }
}
```

MatchesReducer.js

```
import {
  GET_MATCHES,
  ADD_MATCHES_PROFILES,
  RESET_MATCHES,
} from '../actions/types'



const INITIAL_STATE = {
  matchUserIds: {},
  matchUserIdsLoaded: false,
  matchUserProfiles: {},
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MATCHES:
      return {...state, matchUserIds: action.payload, matchUserIdsLoaded: true}
    case ADD_MATCHES_PROFILES:
      //error occurs here
      return {...state, matchUserProfiles: [...state.matchUserProfiles, action.payload]}
    case RESET_MATCHES:
      return {matchUserIds: INITIAL_STATE, matchUserProfiles: INITIAL_STATE}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: It means that you're trying to spread `...` something that is not spreadable. You've got `[...state.matchUserProfiles, action.payload]` (in your last snippet) but `state.matchUserProfiles` is an object in your `INITIAL_STATE`. You perhaps meant `{...state.matchUserProfiles, action.payload}`

Comment: `[...state.matchUserProfiles, action.payload]` is causing the issue. You are better off destructuring the value from state then use it.

Comment: Thanks guys - I'm newish the redux - can you explain how I'd destructure the value and then use it? I've tried changing the {} as Dan suggested, and now it's throwing an error pointing to `action.payload` saying there is an unexpected `,`. So then I declared a `variable = action.payload` and passed the variable instead `      const newProfile = action.payload
      return {...state, matchUserProfiles: {...state.matchUserProfiles, newProfile}}` Is this the best way to do that?

Comment: You should use `{...state.matchUserProfiles, action.payload.matchUserProfiles}`

Comment: @Dan `return {...state, matchUserProfiles: {...state.matchUserProfiles, action.payload.matchUserProfiles}}` gives error `Unexpected token, expected "," (21:78)` pointing to the period between action and payload in: `action.payload.matchUserProfiles`

Comment: I just changed the initial state to matchUserProfiles: [], (instead of {}) and kept everything else in the original question the same, and everything works fine, unless its the very first time.